# Конструктор запросов Eloguent ORM как добавить скобки в условии

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

У меня есть такой запрос:

```
        $matches = Match::select('matches.*', 'team.name as enemy_name')
        ->leftJoin('team', 'team.id', '=', 'matches.enemy_team_id')
        ->where('matches.team_id', '=', $id)
        ->orWhere('matches.enemy_team_id', '=', $id);

    if ($request->only_completed == true) {
        $matches->where('matches.winner', '!=', 0);
    }
```

а мне надо сделать чтоб было типа:

```
where (team_id =  $id or matches.enemy_team_id =  $id) and matches.winner !=  0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       $matches = Match::select('matches.*', 'team.name as enemy_name')
        ->leftJoin('team', 'team.id', '=', 'matches.enemy_team_id')
        ->where(function ($query) use ($id) {
            $query->where('matches.team_id', '=', $id)
                ->orWhere('matches.enemy_team_id', '=', $id);
        });

    if ($request->only_completed == true) {
        $matches->where('matches.winner', '!=', 0);
    }
```